# Any CRUD apps with angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to find out some examples of crud application that wired up with backend like mysql  php or something like that. I found 1 example https://github.com/ccoenraets/angular-cellar but got an error in console and dont know to fix. Have you some useful links?

Comment: the 'CRUD' part of an Angular JS app is going to be highly dependent on your backend.  I'm guessing you're coding the backend in PHP?

Comment: yep, but not care, that can be anything

Comment: A google search for AngularJS CRUD gave me quite a few useful links.  You'll have to be more specific about what you've already tried.

Comment: Did you see builtwith.angularjs.org ? some of them have a link to github too. AngularJS is specially good for CRUD because of the two-way data binding.

Comment: I threw up a CRUD seed for a cross domain angular/django app, you can clone it and check out how it works. https://github.com/zackargyle/angularjs-django-rest-framework-seed

Answer (score 2):

If your backend exposes a RESTful API, ng-admin can be the solution.

https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin

It's open-source, is very easy to customize, and does more than simple CRUD. It's actually designed to build complete backend administrations on top of REST APIS.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some links with a Ruby On Rails CRUD implementation:

1. [angular-crud-app](https://github.com/vgdub/angular-crud-app)
2. [Beryllium Work](http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2012/09/tutorials-on-angularjs-and-rails-2.html)
3. [dillonbuchanan.com](http://www.dillonbuchanan.com/programming/ruby-on-rails-angularjs-resources/)

If you have to use PHP, you could try to understand how the application are structures and try to reproduce the same.

Hope this helps